# Unable to locate element using selenium webdriver even when the element id exists

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Pls, refer the screenshot. I am trying to click the 'Cancel' button as shown in my screenshot. Even when the ID of the element exists, I am not able to click on the button. The popup is neither a new window nor seems like an alert to me. I tried to search if it is an issue with a window handle. but it gives me just one number when I search for the window handles:

```
 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
 System.out.println(handles);
```

Pls suggest..[image: Screenshot of webpage]

[image: Screenshot of Webelement]

Error message received -

> ***Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_g_64d6331f_e460_4a48_890f_b7d7257093d9_ctl00_rtbComments"}
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds***

Comment: Maybe the element you are looking for is inside some iframe, make sure you switch to the fame before performing any action.

Comment: The ID from your error message doesn't match what's in the DOM. `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_g_64d6331f_e460_4a48_890f_b7d7257093d9_ctl00_rtbComments` is from the error message, but what you have highlighted in the screenshot ends in `_rbCancel_input`...why can't you just find by the ID of the button?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry the code piece shown in my screenshot is incorrect. It should have been:  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_g_64d6331f_e460_4a48_890f_b7d7257093d9_ctl00_rbCancel_input")).click();

Comment: you should never use attribute value which has numbers(it can change) , try using the class name

Comment: Actually it is not dynamic. It stays the same all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID you are trying to get does not actually exist. This is because the id dynamically changes each time the browser creates the button, whether this is when you first access it or another action such as javascript.

You can use the attributes and XPath to grab the cancel button as that is static and won't change between sessions.

**C# Code**

```
FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value, 'Cancel')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the id value is changing dynamically.
Try this locator

```
 By.CssSelector("input[value='Cancel']");
```